# How to filter value from api response using rest Assured

Tags: json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a response json as below. where I have multiple nested json in an array having details of spends on particular channel. I need to get the spend value of "EMAIL" only. How can I check for the condition where it is EMAIL get the value for that only ?

Here I need to have two condition where `key == "xyhz"` get the value and inside that value array/list get the value where `channel == "Email"`. So there should be two conditions.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7574461/lucas-nguyen-17.  Could you help me here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is multiple nested array

[image]

So I think JsonPath jayway is better choice in this situation.

```java
List<?> values = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(response, "$.communicationPolicy..rules[?(@.key == 'TRANSACTIONAL')].value[?(@.channel == 'EMAIL')].value");
System.out.println(values);
```

If you still want GPath, then here it is. I use `flatten()` to make 2D aray to 1D array `[[xxx]]` --> `[xxx]`

```java
List<?> value = JsonPath.from(response).get("communicationPolicy.rules.flatten().findAll {it.key == 'TRANSACTIONAL'}.value.flatten().findAll {it.channel == 'EMAIL'}.value");
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do using find{} and findAll{} ?

Comment: @AdilRaza added Gpath expression